# Как реализовать выпадающий текст?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите как в android реализовать выпадающий текст, как показано на изображении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Spinner` смотрели? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 2):

Я бы вам посоветовал бы использовать RecyclerView,был создан в качестве улучшения ListView. Он является более гибким управлением для обработки «списками данных», которые следует модели делегирования проблем и оставляет за собой только одну задачу - переработка предметов.

Вот есть  библиотека, там у них и есть примеры.

[RecyclerView со списками](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/README.md)

Если вас заинтересует, могу выложить пример. 
[image: Мой пример исользования]

Comment: И зачем ему `RecyclerView` лепить для двух элементов?

Comment: на изображении изображен пример того что мне надо реализовать, в реальном списке будет не менее 10 пунктов.

Comment: Ну тогда точно подходит библиотека, причем в неё можно вкладывать различные объекты. То есть для одной пункта один выпадающий текст, для другой с кнопкой и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант использовать ExpandableList:)