# Добавление списка в RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, recyclerview

У меня есть БД в которой у каждой Программы есть Дни, а в каждом дне свои Задания. В активности есть RecyclerView, который отображает все программы в базе данных. Необходимо при нажатии вывести подсписок из дней (а в днях задания, которые они содержат) в той же активности.
Как это можно примерно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите тут, отвечал на похожий вопрос
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664053/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82/664058#664058

Comment: вам нужно срочно узнать о такой дисциплине, как СУБД и составлении query-запросов с условиями выборки. Могу в качестве хорошего старта посоветовать книгу Линн Бейли "Изучаем SQL". Здесь ответить на ваш вопрос весьма затруднительно, так как он слишком общий и не содержит воспроизводимого примера и не совсем понятно, с чем именно у вас проблема. Чтобы дать качественный ответ, потребуется переписать добрую половину вышеупомянутой книги, никто, естественно этого делать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, можно при нажатии на элемент на лету создавать новый адаптер и вызывать метод setAdapter(newAdapter), при этом хранить внутри адаптера ссылку на объект RecyclerView.

Comment: пожалуй это самое неэффективное решение, которое можно было придумать

Comment: @pavlofff, не согласен с вами. Во-первых, вопрос очень общий и не уточняет никаких деталей. Во-вторых, автор хочет изменять состояние UI (не важно каким способом) так, чтобы при нажатии элемента RecyclerView появлялся новый список, контент которого зависит от выбора элемента. Тут уже хотите или нет, придется либо все грузить в память заранее, либо делать запросы в реальном времени и обновлять список. Автор не указал объемы данных, значит будь у него большая база, то первый вариант уже не подходит. Остается лишь грузить на лету, желательно, выводя анимацию загрузки. У вас есть другие идеи?

Comment: я в свою очередь согласен лишь с тем, что вопрос общий и совершенно не понятно, что требуется автору. Предлагать в таких случаях ответы, которые по сути ничего не решают, как то не принято на этом ресурсе - вопрос требует уточнения для того, чтобы получить приемлемое решение. Ваш же ответ (не менее общий и требующий уточнений) не эффективен по причинам порождения ненужных объектов, не оптимизированной логики и гарантированных утечек памяти

Comment: @pavlofff, обоснуйте, пожалуйста, чем гарантирована утечка памяти?

Comment: у меня нет никакого желания что то обосновывать для заведомо не приемлемого решения. Если хотите, создайте тестовый пример и пройдитесь профилировщиком.

Comment: @pavlofff, неприемлемый для вас. Не понимаю, откуда вы взяли класс Cursor, если мы ничего не знаем о природе БД. И то, что они используются очень редко (хотя это тоже мутное такое заявление), не значит, что вместе они гарантируют утечку памяти. Как раз Cursor и будет доставлять данные в Adapter, а Adapter заполнять RecyclerView. Я лишь могу согласиться, что мой ответ можно уточнить, добавив куски кода для примера. В остальном я не нахожу ваши замечания уместными.

Comment: утечку памяти гарантирует идея создавать новые объекты на каждое изменение и хранить в них ссылки на наследника контекста. Ваши же слова о том, что мы ничего не знаем о проблеме в вопросе под собственным ответом, говорит лишь о том, что по правилам данного ресурса этот ответ более не уместен здесь, чем мои замечания к нему

Comment: @pavlofff, Garbage Collector слышали?) Утечка памяти возникнет, если хранить ссылку в объекте, который будет жить дольше, чем объект, на которого мы храним ссылку. Это конкретно про Java. А создавая новый адаптер и добавляя его в RecyclerView, второй остается без всяких ссылок на него, следовательно будет уничтожен GC-ом. Да и, если посмотреть с другой стороны, автор даже не спрашивал как брать данные с БД. Он конкретно сказал, что есть RecyclerView, который отображает ВСЕ программы в БД. А вопрос был как реализовать обновление UI. Один из вариантов - делать новый адаптер. Можно и по-другому.

Comment: В любом случае, предлагать создавать новый адаптер на каждое изменение, говорит лишь о том, что вы очень мало знакомы с устоявшимися практиками работы со списками - это адский дилетанский костыль. Сами вы можете делать в своем приложении, что вам угодно, но не надо предлагать это другим и еще отстаивать, что это здорово.

Comment: @pavlofff, могу ли я узнать почему вы удалили комментарий? Я хотел еще вернуться и внимательно поразмыслить над тем, что вы написали.

Comment: Удалил потому, что был не прав, удержание ссылки на RecyclerView в адаптере, видимо не приведет к утечке. Однако повторю, создавать новый адаптер на каждое изменение это не решение, а костыль. Кстати `Cursor` и природу БД я "взял" из метки [sqlite] под вопросом. Так же хочу заметить, что есть правила данного ресурса, в частности ответы должны содержать рабочее решение вопроса и не основываться на предположении "но мы же ничего не знаем", а комментарии не предполагают дискуссий, размышлений и обсуждений. На этом предлагаю закончить.

Comment: @pavlofff, согласен, что комментарии не для таких обсуждений. Но если вы посмотрите на мою репутацию, то заметите, что оно не позволяет мне писать комментарий. Тогда не о чем и спорить. Автор хотел решение в одном activity, я его предложил. Да, можно по-другому. Напишет автор - уточним ответ. И все же, учитывая ограничение в одно activity, исходные данные и мою невозможность писать комментарий, не считаю мой ответ дилетантским костылем. Спасибо за дискуссию.