# Как правильно работать со сложным ViewHolder?

Tags: android, архитектура

Допустим, есть `RecyclerView` с различными элементами `ViewHolder`.

В одном типе элементов списка может быть семь виджетов `EditText`, в другом - другие компоненты. У каждого типа элементов своя логика валидации и прочее.

Стандартное решение - вынести вьюхолдеры в отдельные классы, понятно. Тем не менее, в адаптере будет куча условий `if`, определяющих, как наполнить вьюхолдер данными, какой вьюхолдер создать для данного типа, и тд.

Затем возникает проблема, что этот же элемент с его небольшой логикой валидации (допустим, что поле не должно начинаться с цифры и содержать меньше 8 символов), мне нужен на другом экране. Да, я могу переиспользовать вьюхолдер, но мне всё равно нужно повторять бойлерплейт с его инициализацией `getItemViewType(), onCreateViewHolder()`...

Как же лучше организовать связку Адаптер-ВьюХолдер?

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос тут, возможно вам подойдет
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664053/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82/664058#664058

Comment: Холдер вообще не предназначен для бизнес-логики и какой то валидации, его задача - хранить ссылку на виджет. Как и сам адаптер не должен выполнять такие функции. Получили значение в айтеме,  обработка выполняется уже "снаружи", передается через интерфейс или делегат уже упомянутый.

Comment: Спасибо, но я немного о другом. Переформулировал вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону решения, описанного в http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates.

Там вводится новая сущность - `AdapterDelegate`. Делегат позволяет разгрузить ваши адаптеры и `ViewHolder`, а также сделать их максимально переиспользуемыми, если списков в приложении много. При этом во `ViewHolder` отсутсвует какая либо логика. Это просто класс-holder ссылок на View элементы (`EditText` и т.д.).
В делегаты вы можете инжектить `Презентеры`, через которые провайдите действия пользователя.

Однако бывают случаи, когда один элемент списка переиспользуется много где, и в этом элементе выполняется, например, "like". Инжектить `Презентер` бывает не очень удобно, так как тогда возникает дублирование кода и протягивание лишних зависимостей, чтобы в конце концов выполнить нужный пользовательский сценарий. 
Поэтому можно заинжектить в данный делегат специальный `UseCase (Interactor)`, который как раз и выполняет пользовательский сценарий - нажатие на кнопку like.

Answer (score 3):

1. Выносите `ViewHolder` из внутреннего и/или анонимного класса в публичный
2. Используйте аннотации типа [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) - здорово облегчают жизнь

Answer (score 1):

В своих проектах я использую эту библиотеку https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Достаточно проста в использовании, поддерживает DiffUtil, Payloads, Nested RecyclerView...

Как использовать:

1) Добавляем интерфейс к вашим моделям

```
public class YourModel implements ViewModel {
    ...
}
```

2) Создаем лейяут для итема RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <TextView android:id = "@+id/title" ... />
    <ImageView android:id = "@+id/image" ... />
    <Button android:id = "@+id/button" ... />
    <CustomView android:id = "@+id/custom" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

3) Инициализируем адаптер

```
mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext());
```

4) Добавляем для каждой модели рендерер

```
mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(new ViewBinder<>(
    R.layout.item_layout, //ID лейяута созданного в пункте 2
    YourModel.class, //класс вашей модели
    (model, finder, payloads) -> finder
        .find(R.id.custom, (ViewProvider<CustomView>) customView -> { ... })
        .setBackground(R.id.image, model.getBackground())
        .setText(R.id.text, model.getText())
        .setOnClickListener(R.id.button, v -> { ... })
));

mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(new ViewBinder<>(
    R.layout.other_item_layout,
    OtherYourModel.class,
    (model, finder, payloads) -> finder 
        //...  
));
```