# Вывод иерархического списка(дерева)

Tags: java, android

Подтолкните на мысль. Как в android приложении реализовать иерархический список, чтобы при клике на родителя он раскрывался, а  ниже его выводились его потомки? Гугл не дал результатов, такое чувство что это нереально)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664053/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82/664058#664058 , посмотрите, возможно вы это имеете ввиду

Comment: `ExpandableListView` из API Android или [сторонние библиотеки](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=expandablerecyclerview&type=) для `RecyclerView`